# Created activity in background and movable to foreground?

Tags: android, android-activity

I've got an activity, which lags when opening first time. Because I want to avoid it, I'm trying to make situation like this:

1. While whole app is opening, MyActivity (**not** main) is launching, but not showing;
2. After clicking proper thing in NavDrawer, MyActivity will show.

It will be once, only on app start, because after one click, everything work normal.
Regards! :)

Comment: Does it shows white blank screen for a few seconds ?

Comment: Well, after selecting activity in NavDrawer, it closes (almost!) NavDrawer, wait about 1,5s and launching proper activity.
**edit**
Oh, and that's because of loading high-res images. I'm talking about only loading activity, inside I repaired lagging by making NestedScrollView.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18343018/optimizing-drawer-and-activity-launching-speed

Comment: Huh, that's piece of code. If I'm using stock one, created by NavDrawerActivity in Android Studio, how can I implement it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I think that problem is solved. I will use tutorial given to me by TGMCians in comments, it should make what I want. Here's the link:
[Optimizing drawer and activity launching speed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18343018/optimizing-drawer-and-activity-launching-speed)
Thanks for help! :)