# Remove an activity from Navigation Drawer application (Android )

Tags: android, xml, fragment, slide, navigation-drawer

I don't know why a screen (first screen) displayed before an other screen (second screen) is called. I want to remove first screen. Fist screen displayed in very short time (<3ms). I don't want to see it. My project is downloaded from this [link](http://developer.android.com/shareables/training/NavigationDrawer.zip).

Main Activity:

```
/*

 * Copyright 2013 The Android Open Source Project
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

package com.example.android.navigationdrawerexample;

import java.util.Locale;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * This example illustrates a common usage of the DrawerLayout widget
 * in the Android support library.
 * <p/>
 * <p>When a navigation (left) drawer is present, the host activity should detect presses of
 * the action bar's Up affordance as a signal to open and close the navigation drawer. The
 * ActionBarDrawerToggle facilitates this behavior.
 * Items within the drawer should fall into one of two categories:</p>
 * <p/>
 * <ul>
 * <li><strong>View switches</strong>. A view switch follows the same basic policies as
 * list or tab navigation in that a view switch does not create navigation history.
 * This pattern should only be used at the root activity of a task, leaving some form
 * of Up navigation active for activities further down the navigation hierarchy.</li>
 * <li><strong>Selective Up</strong>. The drawer allows the user to choose an alternate
 * parent for Up navigation. This allows a user to jump across an app's navigation
 * hierarchy at will. The application should treat this as it treats Up navigation from
 * a different task, replacing the current task stack using TaskStackBuilder or similar.
 * This is the only form of navigation drawer that should be used outside of the root
 * activity of a task.</li>
 * </ul>
 * <p/>
 * <p>Right side drawers should be used for actions, not navigation. This follows the pattern
 * established by the Action Bar that navigation should be to the left and actions to the right.
 * An action should be an operation performed on the current contents of the window,
 * for example enabling or disabling a data overlay on top of the current content.</p>
 */
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
    private CharSequence mTitle;
    private String[] mPlanetTitles;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        SystemClock.sleep(3000);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
        mPlanetTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets_array);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

        // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer opens
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
        // set up the drawer's list view with items and click listener
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.drawer_list_item, mPlanetTitles));
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

        // enable ActionBar app icon to behave as action to toggle nav drawer
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
        // between the sliding drawer and the action bar app icon
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this,                  /* host Activity */
                mDrawerLayout,         /* DrawerLayout object */
                R.drawable.ic_drawer,  /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
                R.string.drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
                R.string.drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
                ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            selectItem(0);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    /* Called whenever we call invalidateOptionsMenu() */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // If the nav drawer is open, hide action items related to the content view
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_websearch).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
         // The action bar home/up action should open or close the drawer.
         // ActionBarDrawerToggle will take care of this.
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        // Handle action buttons
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_websearch:
            // create intent to perform web search for this planet
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH);
            intent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, getActionBar().getTitle());
            // catch event that there's no activity to handle intent
            if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, R.string.app_not_available, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    /* The click listner for ListView in the navigation drawer */
    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            selectItem(position);
        }
    }

    private void selectItem(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Fragment fragment = new PlanetFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(PlanetFragment.ARG_PLANET_NUMBER, position);
        fragment.setArguments(args);

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();

        // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        setTitle(mPlanetTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    /**
     * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
     * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
     */

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    /**
     * Fragment that appears in the "content_frame", shows a planet
     */
    public static class PlanetFragment extends Fragment {
        public static final String ARG_PLANET_NUMBER = "planet_number";

        public PlanetFragment() {
            // Empty constructor required for fragment subclasses
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_planet, container, false);
//            int i = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PLANET_NUMBER);
//            String planet = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets_array)[i];
//
//            int imageId = getResources().getIdentifier(planet.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()),
//                            "drawable", getActivity().getPackageName());
//            ((ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.image)).setImageResource(imageId);
//            getActivity().setTitle(planet);
            return rootView;
        }
    }
}
```

Android Manifest:

```
<!--
  Copyright 2013 The Android Open Source Project

  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
  you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
  You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
  -->

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.navigationdrawerexample"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Activity_main.xml:

```
<!--
  Copyright 2013 The Android Open Source Project

  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
  you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
  You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
-->


<!-- A DrawerLayout is intended to be used as the top-level content view using match_parent for both width and height to consume the full space available. -->
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <!--
         As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
         space available using match_parent in both dimensions.
    -->

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!--
         android:layout_gravity="start" tells DrawerLayout to treat
         this as a sliding drawer on the left side for left-to-right
         languages and on the right side for right-to-left languages.
         The drawer is given a fixed width in dp and extends the full height of
         the container. A solid background is used for contrast
         with the content view.
    -->

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="514dp"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#6d386f"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="51dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="514dp"
        android:background="#6d386f" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/draw_btn"
            android:layout_width="42dp"
            android:layout_height="42dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:background="@drawable/draw_btn" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/puzzle_btn"
            android:layout_width="42dp"
            android:layout_height="42dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/draw_btn"
            android:background="@drawable/puzzle_btn" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/keyboard_btn"
            android:layout_width="47dp"
            android:layout_height="28dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/puzzle_btn"
            android:background="@drawable/keyboard_btn" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/mic_btn"
            android:layout_width="42dp"
            android:layout_height="42dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="27dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/keyboard_btn"
            android:background="@drawable/mic_btn" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cam_btn"
            android:layout_width="42dp"
            android:layout_height="42dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="27dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/mic_btn"
            android:background="@drawable/cam_btn" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

drawer_list_item.xml

```
<!--
  Copyright 2013 The Android Open Source Project

  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
  you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
  You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
  -->

<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"/>
```

fragment_planet.xml

```
<!--
  Copyright 2013 The Android Open Source Project

  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
  you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
  You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
  -->
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="32dp" />

<Button 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hi"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Please help me.

Thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the "First screen displayed in very short time (<3ms)" is the laggy after the navigation fragment has been close, right before the "Planet" shown. This is a common bug (or whatever) of this example.

I have fixed that as follow:

First, I add a new Handler and a Runnable to "do the work in another thread" (as I guess it does).

```
private Handler mHandler;
private Runnable mPendingRunnable;
```

Then, I modify the following methods:

```
/* The click listner for ListView in the navigation drawer */
private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {
        mPendingRunnable = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
                // update the main content by replacing fragments
                Fragment fragment = new PlanetFragment();
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                args.putInt(PlanetFragment.ARG_PLANET_NUMBER, position);
                fragment.setArguments(args);

                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();
            }
        };

        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        setTitle(mPlanetTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    }
}

//

public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
    getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()

    if (mPendingRunnable != null) {
        mHandler.post(mPendingRunnable);
        mPendingRunnable = null;
    }
}
```

Now, your navigation pane should smoothly close, and right after it closed, the planet will show up.

About the duration of the closing/opening process, you should read this thread for more information:

[Speed up 'Navigation Drawer' animation speed on closing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19460683/speed-up-navigation-drawer-animation-speed-on-closing)

So, basically, my answer will clean the laggy of the navigation pane on closing.