# Drag speed of android navigation drawer

Tags: android, navigation, drag, drawer

I noticed when trying to drag the navigation drawer slow from left to right to open it, it won't open as expected. It only shows a slim edge and hides again. You must be quite fast to open it. I tested it with the [sample application](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) from google.
How could I change this behavior? I would like it to open drag speed independent. How could I reach this?

Comment: I think this link will help you: [Speed up 'Navigation Drawer' animation speed on closing?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19460683/speed-up-navigation-drawer-animation-speed-on-closing

Answer (score 0):

I think this link will help you: [Speed up 'Navigation Drawer' animation speed on closing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19460683/speed-up-navigation-drawer-animation-speed-on-closing)

```
public boolean smoothSlideViewTo(... int duration) {
    ...
    return forceSettleCapturedViewAt(... int duration);
}
```

Sorry for the late respone:)

Answer (score -1):

First from below links download the sourcode files:

[**DrawerLayout.java**](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.3_r1/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.java)

[**ViewDrawerHelper.java**](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.3_r1/android/support/v4/widget/ViewDragHelper.java#ViewDragHelper)

and paste the above two files in your applications util package (or where you want) and take reference of this drawer layout in your activity not of `android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout` change your drawer layout reference in activity's layout file,

Now adjust

```
private static final int MAX_SETTLE_DURATION = 600; // ms
```

of ViewDrawerHelper, to speed up just increase the value and to down just decrease the value.

If you want to add action on action bar toggle button then from below links download the source files of

[**ActionBarDrawerToggle.java**](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.L_preview/android/support/v4/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.java#ActionBarDrawerToggle)

[**ActionBarDrawerToggleJellybeanMR2.java**](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.L_preview/android/support/v4/app/ActionBarDrawerToggleJellybeanMR2.java#ActionBarDrawerToggleJellybeanMR2)

[**ActionBarDrawerToggleHoneycomb.java**](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.L_preview/android/support/v4/app/ActionBarDrawerToggleHoneycomb.java#ActionBarDrawerToggleHoneycomb)

and paste the above files in your applications util package (or where you want)
Note:- Make sure the imported packages of each newly added file refers to the file which is in your application project, not of android.support.v4.widget.*;

if the above links are not working please add http://