# Controlling the Navigation Drawer sliding speed

Tags: java, android

I spent a fair amount of time searching the web for some general guidance on which methods or interfaces can I use in order to control the speed with which the Navigation Drawer slides either open or closed , I don't want to use `ActionBarToggle`.

There are some methods like `OnDrawerSlide` and similar, but there aren't any examples or more information on what those methods exactly do.

Any links or tips will be greatly appreciated.Just as an example I would like to be able to click an Item on the Drawer and then to be able to define how fasts the drawer closes, it can be very smooth and slow.

Comment: use The Source Code,  Luke

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this link will help you: [Speed up 'Navigation Drawer' animation speed on closing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19460683/speed-up-navigation-drawer-animation-speed-on-closing)

```
public boolean smoothSlideViewTo(... int duration) {
    ...
    return forceSettleCapturedViewAt(... int duration);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but your code sample doesn't explain anything by itself. Please update to a more meaningful answer