# Unwanted animation of the NavDrawer when getting back to previous Activity

Tags: android, performance, navigation, navigation-drawer

I have a Navigation Drawer that launches activities when items are selected. Here's the problem: when I press back from an Activity, i get back to the previous Activity, but unfortunately i see an animation of the Navigation Drawer closing.
This is an unwanted behaviour: i want to get back and see no animation at all!

Here's my code:

```
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout; //declared globally in my Activity

mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout); //located in my OnCreate()
```

And this is how I close the NavDrawer when I get back to the previous Activity:

```
@Override
public void onResume(){
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.START);

    super.onResume();
}
```

Where is the mistake?

**EDIT**

Here's how i start activities from Navigation Drawer:

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View view, int position) {


            switch(position){

                case 0 : {
                            Intent myIntent = new Intent(NavigationDrawerFragment.this.getActivity(), PreparativiActivity.class);
                            NavigationDrawerFragment.this.startActivity(myIntent);
                            break;
                         }


                case 1 : {
                            Intent myIntent = new Intent(NavigationDrawerFragment.this.getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
                            NavigationDrawerFragment.this.startActivity(myIntent);
                            break;
                         }


                case 2 : {
                            Intent myIntent = new Intent(NavigationDrawerFragment.this.getActivity(), ModulisticaActivity.class);
                            NavigationDrawerFragment.this.startActivity(myIntent);
                            break;
                         }




                case 3 : {
                            Intent myIntent = new Intent(NavigationDrawerFragment.this.getActivity(), PoloActivity.class);
                            NavigationDrawerFragment.this.startActivity(myIntent);
                            break;
                         }


                case 4 : {
                          Intent myIntent = new Intent(NavigationDrawerFragment.this.getActivity(), ContattiActivity.class);
                          NavigationDrawerFragment.this.startActivity(myIntent);
                          break;
                         }


                case 5 : {
                          Intent myIntent = new Intent(NavigationDrawerFragment.this.getActivity(), IntroQuizActivity.class);
                          NavigationDrawerFragment.this.startActivity(myIntent);
                          break;
                         }


                case 6 : {
                           Intent myIntent = new Intent(NavigationDrawerFragment.this.getActivity(), CreditiActivity.class);
                           NavigationDrawerFragment.this.startActivity(myIntent);
                           break;
                          }


                default: { Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Errore di sistema numero 001 ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                         }




            }

        }
```

Comment: Please provide the code where you're starting Activities when items are selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not close the Drawer when resuming the Activity:

```
@Override
public void onResume(){
mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.START); //this should have been done before
super.onResume();
}
```

Instead you should **close it when starting an Activity** from the drawer:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view, int position) {
        switch(position){

            case 0 : {
                        Intent myIntent = new Intent(NavigationDrawerFragment.this.getActivity(), PreparativiActivity.class);
                        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.START);
                        NavigationDrawerFragment.this.startActivity(myIntent);
                        break;
                     }
//And so on...
```

Another possibility (to hide the close-Animation even more) would be to close the drawer after starting the new Activity:

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View view, int position) {


        switch(position){

            case 0 : {
                        Intent myIntent = new Intent(NavigationDrawerFragment.this.getActivity(), PreparativiActivity.class);
                        NavigationDrawerFragment.this.startActivity(myIntent);
                        break;
                     }


            case 1 : {
                        Intent myIntent = new Intent(NavigationDrawerFragment.this.getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
                        NavigationDrawerFragment.this.startActivity(myIntent);
                        break;
                     }


            case 2 : {
                        Intent myIntent = new Intent(NavigationDrawerFragment.this.getActivity(), ModulisticaActivity.class);
                        NavigationDrawerFragment.this.startActivity(myIntent);
                        break;
                     }




            case 3 : {
                        Intent myIntent = new Intent(NavigationDrawerFragment.this.getActivity(), PoloActivity.class);
                        NavigationDrawerFragment.this.startActivity(myIntent);
                        break;
                     }


            case 4 : {
                      Intent myIntent = new Intent(NavigationDrawerFragment.this.getActivity(), ContattiActivity.class);
                      NavigationDrawerFragment.this.startActivity(myIntent);
                      break;
                     }


            case 5 : {
                      Intent myIntent = new Intent(NavigationDrawerFragment.this.getActivity(), IntroQuizActivity.class);
                      NavigationDrawerFragment.this.startActivity(myIntent);
                      break;
                     }


            case 6 : {
                       Intent myIntent = new Intent(NavigationDrawerFragment.this.getActivity(), CreditiActivity.class);
                       NavigationDrawerFragment.this.startActivity(myIntent);
                       break;
                      }


            default: { Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Errore di sistema numero 001 ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                     }
            } //switch end
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.START);
}//onClick end
```

Edit:
One problem of this solution could be that the closing-animation seems a bit laggy. This is because the Android-system is already busy with rendering the new Activity, so there is not enough capacity for rendering the closing-animation anymore.

To **solve this problem you could speed up the animation** (so there would be less animation-rendering). Unfortunately, doing this seems to be a bit complicated.

To learn more about speeding up the animation, read here:
[Speed up 'Navigation Drawer' animation speed on closing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19460683/speed-up-navigation-drawer-animation-speed-on-closing)

Comment: Thank you mate! You saved my life! I have only one more question... Now when i lauch an activity the animation of drawer closing seems to be a bit laggy...Can you tell me some possible reasons?

Comment: I updated my answer to give you some hints. I think there's no built-in solution. Sorry mate!