# Disable rotation animation on clicking 'navigation drawer indicator' ( hamburger icon)

Tags: android, performance

How to disable rotation animation on clicking 'navigation drawer indicator'
( hamburger icon) ?

I'm using a Htc model on geny motion emulator(1 GB ram). On clicking Navigation drawer icon, there is a slight lag on nav panel sliding (opening and closing).

So,I think, disabling animation would make sliding smoother.

(I'm using navigation drawer default template)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `setDrawerSlideAnimationEnabled(boolean)` to enable or disable the drawer arrow animation when the drawer position changes. An example of this would be:

```
// Installs drawer toggle
drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout,
                 R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close);

// Disables animation
drawerToggle.setDrawerSlideAnimationEnabled(false);
```

Comment: But still a slight lag is there, on opening drawer. Any idea to fix it ?

Comment: It would be hard to suggest anything without any code. You could refer to [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32455989/7461132) and see if it helps.

Comment: I'm using the default navigation drawer template, not any fragment for its implementation

Comment: If the other answers didn't help, please post the relevant code as an edit in your question.

Comment: I'll post it as a different question.Thanks for your help