# BottomNavigationView lags on fragment transaction

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, material-design, bottomnavigationview

## The problem

I'm using the `BottomNavigationView` from the Android Design Support Library on one of my Activities, alongside with Fragments for each navigation item.

Each time I select an item on the bar, I do a fragment transaction, like the snippet below (some parts of the code was removed for brevity):

```
private var fragmentToSet: Fragment? = null

private val onNavigationItemSelectedListener = BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->

    fragmentToSet = when (item.itemId) {
        // Choose fragment based on selection
        // ...
    }

// ...

supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, fragmentToSet)
                .commit()
}
```

The problem is... The bottom bar animation gets super laggy, and only finishes after the fragment is fully loaded and displayed on the screen.

This issue [is not exactly new](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17491557/drawerlayouts-item-click-when-is-the-right-time-to-replace-fragment) since it can also happen while using the Navigation Menu, but at least it's possible to solve it by using the `DrawerLayout.DrawerListener` and do the actual Fragment transaction only after the drawer is closed.

## What I've tried so far

I tried to "cache" the fragments, holding their reference to avoid recreating the objects every time (e.g. `MyFragment.newInstance()`), but that didn't work.

I also tried to use handlers, which kinda solved the problem, but it might lead me to an exception [in some cases](https://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/08/fragment-transaction-commit-state-loss.html). Something like the snippet below:

```
handler.postDelayed({changeFragment(fragmentToSet!!)}, 200)
```

Is there a way to solve this issue without using handlers (or other async calls), on a similar fashion to [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17492040/4070469) while using the Navigation Menu?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I handled this situation by hiding and showing fragments using fragment manager. I wrote a sample code to deal with it as below.

```
class MainActivity : BaseActivity() {

    private val homeFragment = HomeFragment.newInstance()
    private val categoryFragment = CategoryFragment.newInstance()
    private val searchFragment = SearchFragment.newInstance()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener)
        navigation.menu.findItem(R.id.navigation_home).isChecked = true

        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.containerFrameLayout, homeFragment)
                .add(R.id.containerFrameLayout, categoryFragment)
                .add(R.id.containerFrameLayout, searchFragment)
                .commit()
        setTabStateFragment(TabState.HOME).commit()
    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        if (supportFragmentManager.backStackEntryCount > 0 || !homeFragment.isHidden) {
            super.onBackPressed()
        } else {
            setTabStateFragment(TabState.HOME).commit()
            navigation.menu.findItem(R.id.navigation_home).isChecked = true
        }
    }

    private fun setTabStateFragment(state: TabState): FragmentTransaction {
        supportFragmentManager.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE)
        val transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fragment_enter, R.anim.fragment_exit)
        when (state) {
            TabState.HOME -> {
                transaction.show(homeFragment)
                transaction.hide(categoryFragment)
                transaction.hide(searchFragment)
            }
            TabState.CATEGORY -> {
                transaction.hide(homeFragment)
                transaction.show(categoryFragment)
                transaction.hide(searchFragment)
            }
            TabState.SEARCH -> {
                transaction.hide(homeFragment)
                transaction.hide(categoryFragment)
                transaction.show(searchFragment)
            }
        }
        return transaction
    }

    private val mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener = BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->
        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.navigation_home -> {
                setTabStateFragment(TabState.HOME).commit()
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
            R.id.navigation_category -> {
                setTabStateFragment(TabState.CATEGORY).commit()
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
            R.id.navigation_search -> {
                setTabStateFragment(TabState.SEARCH).commit()
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
        }
        false
    }

    internal enum class TabState {
        HOME,
        CATEGORY,
        SEARCH,
    }

}
```

Comment: That's indeed really interesting! I'll implement it and test it. Thanks!

Comment: @Mauker: If it works for you, please accept the answer dude ;)

Comment: Of course! Gimme a few and I'll be back. Thanks again.

Comment: It solved like 90% of the problem. Here's what I noticed: On the first time I tap on the navigation bar, it still lags, but after the second time it works wonders. I believe that this can be solved if I change how I'm creating the view. But since it works on the "second tap", I'll mark it as solved. Brilliant solution.

Comment: Thank you man. I think you should revise your codes related to fragment views and try to make them lighter by using RecyclerView, maybe ViewStub, etc...

Comment: Exactly. I'll make those changes on the view. Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry to bother again, but I found this: https://thomasclowes.com/android-fragments-and-memory/ And I'm facing a memory issue since I'm adding 5 fragments to my container, the memory usage spikes.

Comment: Anybody with Java version of this?